# What are most recent research work on the problem of key phrases extraction from a text corpus?

Tags: references, information-retrieval, text-summarization

I am interested in the problem of extracting key phrases from a text corpus. This is different from the keyword extraction problem, which is only for a particular document. This problem helps us, for example, to construct a domain-specific dictionary/taxonomy/ontology from that domain's set of documents.

I can only find some old research papers, like 20 years ago, on this problem. I would like to know if there are any recent research work? What are the best or most popular methods on this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this question is "too broad" as it asks only for a list of references, not details of how to do everything.

Comment: Thanks @PeterFlom, currently I use nltk's [collocations](http://www.nltk.org/howto/collocations.html) to find frequent bigrams, but the results include non-domain terms. I am looking for better approaches.

Comment: @Arnold: Could you reference some of that old work?